# Scrolling to a certain item in FlatList - without known exact width

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a horizontal FlatList in my app

there's many items in the FlatList

each item is a text , with no exact width or characters length

so , no fixed width exist

how to scroll to a certain element in this case

scrollToIndex and scrollToOffset depends on giving a width which I don't have

I intend to use [scrollToItem](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/flatlist#scrolltoitem)

per documentation , it requires the item prop

> 'item' (object) - The item to scroll to. Required.

what's this item prob is about ?

it is not clear in the documentation and no examples online

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
let data = [ {key: 0, text: “A”}, {key: 0, text: “B”} ]

<FlatList
    // Do something when animation ended
    onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) => this.onScrollEnd(e)} 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
        // Max 5 items visibles at once
        {length: Dimensions.get('window').width / 5, offset: Dimensions.get('window').width / 5 * index, index}   
    )}
    horizontal
    // Here is the magic : snap to the center of an item
    snapToAlignment={'center'}  
    // Defines here the interval between to item (basically the width of an item with margins)
    snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width / 5}  
    renderItem={ ({item, index}) =>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.scrollToIndex(/* scroll to that item */)} <!— index ->
            style={styles.cell}>
            <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }
/>
```